# Schema Registry won't start after upgrading to Confluent 4.1

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I have recently upgraded Confluent to 4.1 but schema registry seems to have some issues. On `confluent start` schema-registry (and consequently ksql-server) cannot start.

Here's the error I get in the logs of schema-registry:

```
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,426] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:65)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:203)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:63)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:41)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:165)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreException: Failed to write Noop record to kafka store.
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:139)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:201)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreException: Failed to write Noop record to kafka store.
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.getLatestOffset(KafkaStore.java:423)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.waitUntilKafkaReaderReachesLastOffset(KafkaStore.java:276)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:137)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:77)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:29)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.getLatestOffset(KafkaStore.java:418)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,430] INFO Shutting down schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry:726)
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,430] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Shutting down (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:66)
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,431] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Stopped (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:66)
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,440] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Shutdown completed (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:66)
[2018-04-20 11:27:38,446] INFO KafkaStoreReaderThread shutdown complete. (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:227)
```

I have no clue why this error is reported and the error messages are not that meaningful to me.

After failing, `confluent start schema-registry` and `confluent start ksql-server` bring both services up but when starting KSQL  I get the following warning:

```
**************** WARNING ******************
Remote server address may not be valid:
Error issuing GET to KSQL server
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: Could not connect to the server.
*******************************************
```

When trying to run a command (e.g. `show tables;`) the following error is reported:

```
ksql> show tables;
Error issuing POST to KSQL server
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: Could not connect to the server.
```

**EDIT:** I've fixed this by destroying current run (`confluent destroy)` but it would be interesting if someone could explain this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the info you've posted it *feels* like you may have had some zombie processes or bad data somewhere, though I can't be sure.

The Schema Registry was complaining that it couldn't write a message to Kafka, because the Kafka broker was complaining that it didn't own the topic partition the Schema Registry was writing to.  This *might* of been caused by a previous Kafka broker, (from the old install), still running.

Did you `confluent stop` before upgrading?

Using `confluent destroy`, as you did, to flatted/reset the installation is always a good option, as long as you're not precious about your data.  Checking for spurious processes, (or using the old 'reboot machine' trick), can also be a good place to start when things aren't behaving as you'd expect.

Glad its all sorted now :D

Andy

Comment: I am not sure if I ran `confluent stop` before upgrading. Most probably I did not so I guess that this might caused the issue! Cheers.